# How can I say "same direction" with one word?

Tags: terminology, vectors

How can I say "**of opposite direction**" and "**of the same direction**" (eg when referring to vectors) in one word?

Comment: If you want one word for both of them, it is parallel.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I'll try using the words "parallel" and "anti-parallel".

Comment: Anti-parallels and parallels are used in Euclidean geometry. For anti parallels a vector has relatively a negative sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I don't know how to describe in English this pair of vectors: -->, --> (and this: <--, <--) using a single word. They are parallel, indeed, but how do I refer to their direction? Is there a single word or should I use the expressions "opposite (or same) direction"?

Comment: Same direction (-->,--> or <--,<--) = like vectors, opposite direction (<--,--> or -->,<--) = unlike vectors, same or opposite = parallel/collinear vectors

Comment: Alright! Thank you A.G.!